# what is the different between Single List and List Node?

Tags: java, linked-list

```
public static SingleList copy(SingleList list1){
    SingleList list2 = new SingleList();
    ListNode current=list1.head;
    while (current != null){
        list2.addLast(current.getData());
        current=current.getNext();
    }
    return list2;
}
```

I do not know what the function of this method or even how it work on computer not even know the difference between node and singlelist!!

Comment: We could only guess! SingleList is probably a singly linked list and ListNode is one node in the list. copy() is a method that makes a copy of an entire list of nodes.

Comment: ok I got it but how it works!!!

Comment: it`s adding only objects from list1  that have 'head' property not null to new Singlelist

Answer (score 0):

`ListNode` is a **node** in a **linked list**. `SingleList` is a **linked list**.

To draw an analogy - a node is a link in a chain; the linked list is the chain itself.

Answer (score 0):

ListNode is a node in the linked list and there is some code to better understand the ListNode.

```
public class List
 {
     // return a linked list based on parameters list and soFar
     public static ListNode process(ListNode list, ListNode soFar)
     {
         if (list == null) {
             return soFar;
         }
         else {
             ListNode temp = list.getNext();
             list.setNext(soFar);
             return process(temp,list);
         }
      }

      // return a new linked list based on parameter n

      public static ListNode create(int n)
      {
        ListNode list = null;
        for(int k=1; k <= n; k++) {
            list = new ListNode(new String(""+k), list);
        }
        return list;
      }

      // print a linked list

      public static void print(ListNode list)
      {
        while (list != null) {
            System.out.print(list.getValue()+" ");
            list = list.getNext();
        }
        System.out.println();
      }
 }
```